# Trying to build two graphs/charts from a two column spreadsheet in excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a two column spreadsheet like so that indicates the the usage of a website.  A snap shot is taking every 15 minutes and shows what pages of the website are currently displayed:

```
Time                 |         Location
2011-08-24-02.00.16  |  Enter Run Record
2011-08-24-02.00.16  |  /user/PtManagerFull.jsp
2011-08-24-02.00.16  |  /common/master.jsp
2011-08-24-02.00.16  |  Enter Run Record
2011-08-24-02.00.16  |  Enter Run Record
2011-08-24-02.00.16  |  Enter Run Record
2011-08-24-02.00.16  |  /common/master.jsp
2011-08-24-02.15.10  |  Enter Run Record
```

I want one graph (line or bell) that will show the over all usage over the course of a day with the Y Axis being amount of pages being used for that time (ie 7 pages being view at 2011-08-24-02.00.16) and the X axis will be the time of day in 15 minute intervals.

Next I want a chart that will indicate the amount of users viewing what pages at any point in time - so at 2011-08-24-02.00.16 there were 4 users viewing Enter Run Record.

I just don't have any idea where to start and my excel skills are rusty, can anyone point me in the right direction or offer any pointers?

Answer (score -1):

One Word [PowerPivot](http://www.powerpivot.com/) , everything you need to know to get started and use the best of the latest analysis on your data + more.

Comment: -1, I love Powerpivot but your answer doesn't provide any clue on how to solve the OP problem.